# Getting error message "Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different component" in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am getting warning message "Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different component"  in functional component. Not sure why i am getting this warning message. There is some problem with useEffect i guess. I tried to show error and success message in handleSubmit function but reducer make some delay to send updated state into component. Source code as follow

```
const CategoryCreate = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  // const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  // const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // searching filter
  // step1
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCateories();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const { categories, loading, categoryName, error, errorMsg } = useSelector(
    (state) => ({
      ...state.category,
    })
  );

  const loadCateories = () => {
    dispatch(loadCategoryStart());
  };

  console.log("==errorMsg", errorMsg);

  const {
    user: { token },
  } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  if (errorMsg) {
    toast.error(errorMsg && errorMsg);
    dispatch(setErrorMsgEmpty());
  }

  if (categoryName) {
    toast.success(`${categoryName} is created`);
    setName("");
    loadCateories();
    dispatch(setCategoryEmpty());
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createCategoryStart({ name, token }));
  };
 
return (
<>
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        autoFocus
        required
      />
      <br />
      <button className="btn btn-outline-primary">Save</button>
       
       <hr />
        {categories &&
          categories.length &&
          categories.map((c) => (
            <div key={c._id} className="alert alert-secondary">
              {c.name}{" "}
            </div>
          ))}
    </div>
  </form>
</>
)
}
```

Comment: Were you in debug mode when you get the error?

Comment: Probably you're updating something in header state ( the reducers) and that's initiating the render on the Header component as well, You're on redux?

Comment: I am getting warning when i am dispatching -> dispatch(setCategoryEmpty());

Comment: I am not updating in Header component

Comment: Did you try putting `if (categoryName) {...}` inside `useEffect` ?

Comment: useEffect can't be use conditionally

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<form onSubmit={()=> handleSubmit}>`